# Powershell - filenames that match two (or more) patterns

Tags: powershell

To find files in a directory that have both "foo" and "bar" in the filename, we can use:

`Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*foo*" -and $_.Name -like "*bar*"}`

Is there a more elegant way to write (or query for) this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you consider your command inelegant? If you're just after more terse code, this might be better on Code Review.

Incidentally, I don't think that command would work.

If you want to use `-like`, then add wildcards:

```
gci | ? {$_.Name -like "*foo*" -and $_.Name -like "*bar*"}
```

If you don't want to use wildcards, use `-match`:

```
gci | ? {$_.Name -match "foo" -and $_.Name -match "bar"}
```

There are many ways to skin a cat

```
gci *foo* | ? {$_.Name -in (gci *bar*).Name}
```

I think more elegant code is subjective and really depends on your coding style. I personally prefer your line of code as it's not cryptic at all, and it's fairly compact for what it does.

Comment: note that the `in` Operater only works in PS3.0+

Comment: Thanks, my original post was lacking wildcards, I've edited the post. While my code is straight forward and easy to read, I naturally want to avoid having to re-write variables (`$_.Name`). I was also hoping for a means to not require `-and`. It would have been preferable to be able to sequence multiple condition like `"*foo*","*bar*"`, where the results are all objects who match all conditions.

Answer (score 2):

How I understand the title of this question the answer would be like one of:

```
'*.txt','*.log' | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem $_ }   # 'pure' Powershell
where.exe /r . *.txt *.log                              # external command
```

But for just getting files that have 'foo' **and** 'bar' in their names (which I consider one pattern) some obvious solutions could be:

```
Get-ChildItem *foo*bar*                           # if the order is given
Get-ChildItem  `
  | Where-Object Name -match 'foo.*bar|bar.*foo'  # if not
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use regular expressions match:

`Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)"`

If you are after shorter version(s), you could also abbreviate it to:

`gci |? {$_.Name -match "(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)"`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities:

```
gci | ? Name -like *foo* | ? Name -like *bar*

gci *foo* | ? Name -like *bar*
```

I agree with ST8 though that your version is fine.